# Flying to Australia

Tags: curated-data, wolfram-alpha-queries, geography

I want to compare different flight routes to Australia and their lengths. So far I have written:

```
departure =
 Entity["City", {"BuenosAires", "BuenosAires", "Argentina"}];

destination =
 Entity["City", {"Perth", "WesternAustralia", "Australia"}];

km =
 ToString@QuantityMagnitude@Round@(GeoDistance[departure, destination]) <> " km";

GeoGraphics[
 {
  {Thick, Red, GeoPath[{departure, destination}]},
  Style[Text[km, GeoPosition[destination]], Blue, 14, Bold]
  },
 GeoCenter -> destination,
 GeoProjection -> "Mercator",
 GeoRange -> "World",
 ImageSize -> 400,
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

My problem: To specify a city with Mathematica I have to include its federal state / administrative division, which, in many cases, I don' t know. So I have to google and manually input it. Since I want to automate the program for other cities the question is:

How can I persuade Mathematica to tell me that Perth, Australia, is part of Western Australia and use this answer as automated input?

Comment: Use free-form input (you find it under the menu "Insert") as in Yves' answer with the query "Perth, Australia" and then use `InputForm` on the result.

Comment: @Pickett or simply start on a new line with "=" :D

Comment: @YvesKlett I use the keyboard shortcut, but I think it varies between operating systems so I thought it was safer to indicate where to locate it. With `=` you can't append `// InputForm` so it becomes a two-step process!

Comment: If what you actually want is the answer, rather than the way to compute it with Mathematica, the [Great Circle Mapper](http://www.gcmap.com/) does the job well. For example, [Perth to Buenos Aires](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=PER-EZE). In either case, be aware that an actual flight from Perth to Buenos Aires would *not* take the indicated route directly over the south pole because that would leave it without any possibility of diversions if something went wrong. Ask on [travel.se] or [aviation.se] for more information on that kind of thing.

Comment: Many thanks @ David Richerby for the great links :)

Comment: @Eldo: very nice problem. But notice that the "geodesic" path (great circle) is usually not follwed by the airlines, mainly because of the prevailing winds. BTW, taking these into account (in some simplified manner) would be an interesting extension to your problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `Interpreter` without federal state or country.

Works even for small german towns :)

```
Interpreter["City"]["Memmingen"]
GeoPosition[%]
GeoGraphics[%]
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

Also you could ask for the airport:

```
town = Interpreter["City"]["Memmingen"];
airport = Interpreter["Airport"]["Memmingen"];
GeoPosition[{town, airport}]
```

[image]

or just use the nearest airport

```
GeoNearest["Airport", town]
```

Answer (score 12):

You could use the official ICAO abbreviation:

`Entity["Airport", "KLAX"]`

which makes sense because you will only be able to use officially named airports most of the time anyway.

You can always get those (or the city details) via a W|A query and work your way from there (no googling involved):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or like this (although it misses Van Nuys):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks @ Yves - this really helps and is much shorter and clearer :)

Comment: you could use "Interpreter["City"]["Perth"]", too

Comment: @Phab even though your suggestion killed my kernel the first time around, please add this as another answer ;-)

Comment: @Phab I fully agree with Yves Klett, especially if you would append `InputForm` :)

Comment: even better - search for the nearest airport:

GeoNearest["Airport", yourTown]

Comment: @Phab your answer is much better as it provides the programmatic way...

Comment: @YvesKlett Usually I don't like to use the W|A query when it's not necessary ;-)

Comment: @Phab I almost never use it - hence my interactive fumbling :D  My only defense is that I know a few airports by heart, thus the direct (pardon the pun) approach.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to your nice answers and comments I found a solution to my problem:

```
FlightPath[cities_List, pro_: "AzimuthalEquidistant"] :=

 Module[{lc = Length@cities, color, dest, dist, entity, legend, pair, path},

  color = {Red, Darker@Green, Blue, Black, Orange, Purple};
  entity = Interpreter["City"][#] & /@ cities;
  dest = GeoPosition@First@entity;
  pair = Map[{entity[[#]], entity[[1]]} &, Range[2, lc]];
  path = Transpose[{Take[color, lc - 1], GeoPath /@ pair}];
  dist = Map[# <> " km" &, ToString /@ QuantityMagnitude@Round@(GeoDistance @@@ pair)];
  legend = Table[(Rest@cities)[[n]] <> " " <> dist[[n]], {n, 1, lc - 1}];

  Legended[
   GeoGraphics[
    {Thick, Sphere[dest, 0.1], path},
    GeoCenter -> dest,
    GeoProjection -> pro,
    GeoRange -> "World",
    ImageSize -> 400,
    Frame -> True],
   Placed[LineLegend[color, legend], After]]]
```

It works for up to 6 departure cities. The first city in the list is the destination.

```
FlightPath[{"Perth", "BuenosAires", "Berlin", "NewYork", "Lagos"}, "Mercator"]
```

[image]